# Magento share product on instagram

Tags: product, php

I need to share magento product link on Instagram like facebook and twitter. Can anyone provide some idea How to share the product link on Instagram?

Comment: I don't think Instagram supports share link feature. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542054/does-instagram-have-share-button-or-not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use share this tool. This will give you icons and sharing links. For sample I have added code here. You can also generate new using this which is free and open source, [http://www.sharethis.com/] 
Copy the span tags and place them where you want your buttons to appear in the code.

```
<span class='st_' displayText=''></span>
<span class='st_instagram' displayText='Instagram Badge'></span>
```

Copy the script tags and place them inside and at the end of your "head" tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "791bb30f-74a2-4e0f-bde5-5bc23d04c358", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});</script>
```

Comment: I have added above code in my .phtml file. I can see "Instagram Badge", but it is not sharing anything on instagram. It is just allowing me to login in insta.
Will you please let me know how to share product or site url in insta?
Thank for assist in advance.

Comment: it is not giving products sharing link just opening instagram